# In Firebird, how do I write multiple if statements in a procedure?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm writing an sql script in Firebird for an assignment. First, I have to create a 2 column table and add some values (the values aren't supposed to do anything yet)

```
--Create the table
create table salary_class (
class varchar(5),
occurrence int ) ;

commit work;

--Add Values to our table
insert into salary_class (class, occurrence)
values ('ELITE', 0);
insert into salary_class (class, occurrence)
values ('HIGH', 0);
insert into salary_class (class, occurrence)
values ('MID', 0);
insert into salary_class (class, occurrence)
values ('LOW', 0);

commit work;
```

After that worked is committed, I create a procedure. It is supposed to return a certain string based on the number that is passed into it.

```
--Create f_class procedure
set term # ;
create procedure f_class(salary SALARY)

returns (lv VARCHAR(10)) as
begin
    --If statements for each occurrence level
    if (salary <= 39999) then
    lv = 'LOW';
    suspend;

    if (salary <= 67999) then
    lv = 'MID';
    suspend;

    if (salary <= 99999) then
    lv = 'HIGH';
    suspend;

    if (salary >= 100000) then
    lv = 'ELITE';
    suspend;

end#

set term ; #

--Demonstrate that f_class function works correctly
  select lv from f_class(20000);
  select lv from f_class(67999);
  select lv from f_class(68000);
  select lv from f_class(120000);
```

Calling the function gives me

```
LV
null
null
null
ELITE
```

But it's supposed to give me

```
LV
LOW
MID
HIGH
ELITE
```

If anyone could shine some light on this, it would be much appreciated. Been pulling my hair out over the Firebird manual the past 2 days.

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using? Note that stored procedures are not functions. Also your output doesn't match the actual output of your stored procedure. Because of the presence of 4 unconditional `suspend` statements, each invocation will return 4 values, right now you have only posted the output of `select lv from f_class(120000);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code. The first problem is that you use `suspend` unconditionally, which means that each invocation of the stored procedure returns 4 rows, which depending on the condition may contain a `null` value, or a previous value.

This doesn't seem what you expect, as the expected output of your question seems to match the expectation for each individual salary, while the actual output is the output of the last statement (`select lv from f_class(120000);`).

The second problem is that you use individual `if` statements, which leads to multiple conditions being evaluated (eg value 1 will return`low`, `mid` and `high` (2x), and value 67999 will return `null`, `mid` and `high` (2x), etc).

To solve your problems there are a few solutions:

1. Use a chained [`if .. then .. else`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-ifthen):

   ```
   if (salary <= 39999) then
       lv = 'LOW';
   else if (salary <= 67999) then
       lv = 'MID';
   else if (salary <= 99999) then
       lv = 'HIGH';
   else if (salary >= 100000) then
       lv = 'ELITE';

   suspend;
   ```

   The single `suspend` will also prevent the output of multiple rows.
2. Replace the `if`-statements with a searched [`case`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-case):

   ```
   lv = case 
           when salary <= 39999 then 'LOW'
           when salary <= 67999 then 'MID'
           when salary <= 99999 then 'HIGH'
           when salary >= 100000 then 'ELITE'
        end;

   suspend;
   ```

   You can also replace the last `when salary >= 100000 then 'ELITE'` with `else 'ELITE'`

However you describing this as a *function* in your question makes me think that this might be the wrong solution altogether. Stored procedures are not functions, they are procedures that optionally return values or - with `suspend` - produce dynamic 'tables' (a result set). If you need a real function, and you are using Firebird 3, then use [stored functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-ddl-function):

```
create function f_class(salary SALARY) returns varchar(10)
as
begin
    return case 
        when salary <= 39999 then 'LOW'
        when salary <= 67999 then 'MID'
        when salary <= 99999 then 'HIGH'
        when salary >= 100000 then 'ELITE'
    end;
end
```

You can then use it like

```
select f_class(120000) from rdb$database;
```

The use of `rdb$database` is purely for illustration here, a stored function can be used anywhere a normal SQL function can be used.

Comment: Thanks you, this was the answer I needed. For some reason I couldn't get the syntax for the if else if to work until you showed me. I was messing around with a lot of the structure, that's why I had so many suspends in there just trying to get it to work.

Comment: @TrpCode what you tried to do probably was using compound operator, `begin .... end` - like this: `if (salary <= 39999) then begin
 lv = 'LOW'; suspend; end  if (salary <= 67999) then begin lv = 'MID'; suspend; end .....`