# Error when trying to create a function in firebird sql

Tags: sql, firebird

Here is the function that is causing the error

```
set term # ; 
create function f_class (salary int)
    returns varchar(5);
    as
        declare klass varchar(5);
    BEGIN
        IF salary < 40000
        THEN SET klass = 'LOW';
        else if salary < 68000 and salary > 39999
        then set klass = 'MID';
        else if salary < 100000 and salary > 67999
        then set klass = 'HIGH';
        else if salary > 100000
        then set klass = 'ELITE';
        end if;
        return klass;

    END#
    set term ; #
```

I am getting this error with my function

```
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

SQL Message : -104
Invalid token

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, column 8
function
```

and I'm not sure why.

Comment: What is the Firebird server version? Stored functions are available since version 3.

Comment: Which version of Firebird are you using?

Comment: BTW: Are you the same person as the asker of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962078/in-firebird-how-do-i-write-multiple-if-statements-in-a-procedure ? If so, you might want to consider asking Stack Overflow for your accounts to be merged. You shouldn't be creating multiple accounts.

Comment: Your function has a lot of other syntax errors: semi-colon after the `returns`-clause, missing parenthesis around the conditions in the if, use of `set` to modify a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The [`create function`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-psql-funcs) feature was introduced in Firebird 3. The error you get means you are using Firebird 2.5 or earlier. If you want to use `create function`, you'll need to upgrade to Firebird 3.

As I commented yesterday you also have several other syntax errors in your code:

- semi-colon after the returns-clause,
- missing parenthesis around the conditions in the if,
- use of `set` to modify a variable, you need to use assignment without `set`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be written like below.

```
set term # ; 
create function f_class1 (salary integer)
    returns varchar(5)
    as
        declare klass varchar(5);
    BEGIN
        IF (salary < 40000) then
        klass = 'LOW';
        else if ((salary < 68000) and (salary > 39999)) then
        klass = 'MID';
        else if ((salary < 100000) and (salary > 67999)) then 
        klass = 'HIGH';
        else if (salary > 100000) then 
        klass = 'ELITE';        
        return klass;
    END#
set term ; #
```